# Does Dynamic Linq cause sql injection?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, code-injection

we are using dynamic linq to sort the IQueryable list, the code is as:

```
foreach (string sortField in sort)
{
    if (sortField.StartsWith("0"))
    {
        sortFields.Add(string.Format("{0} ASC", sortField.TrimStart('0')));
    }
    else if (sortField.StartsWith("1"))
    {
        sortFields.Add(string.Format("{0} DESC", sortField.TrimStart('1')));
    }
    else
    {
        sortFields.Add(sortField);
    }
    return query.OrderBy(String.Join(",", sortFields));
}
```

The problem the `sort` value is from user input, is it dangerous ??

We are using HP fortify to scan the code, and this tool gives us the `SQL injection: Linq` issue, I have no idea of the reason...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `String.Format` to create part of a SQL expression, then you are injecting user code into SQL.

Ultimately the `sortField`s will be put into the SQL `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT ...
ORDER BY sortField1 ASC, sortField2 DESC, ...
```

Imagine the user enters something like `1Name; DROP ALL TABLES --` for the first sort field.

Now you have

```
SELECT ...
ORDER BY Name ASC; DROP ALL TABLES --, sortField2 DESC
```

Which could be very bad if your query will process multiple statements.

Comment: how could I prevent this with dynamic linq  ?